# Model binding to Lists

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-binding

How do I make the default modelbinding handle Lists?

Let’s say I have a ShoppingCart class, which has a ShoppingCartItem List:

```
Public Class ShoppingCart
  Public Property CouponCode As String
  Public Property Items As New List(Of ShoppingCartItem)
End Class

Public Class ShoppingCartItem
  Public Property Title As String
  Public Property Count As Integer
End Class
```

My view looks like this (as per the advice from [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx), and [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx), blogpost):

```
@ModelType VAVTag.LuckyDraw.ShoppingCart

@Code
  Layout = Nothing
End Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
  <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
  @Using Html.BeginForm()
    @<fieldset>
      <legend>ShoppingCart</legend>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.CouponCode)
      <hr />
      @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Items)

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  End Using
</body>
</html>
```

The items are rendered using an EditorTemplate (thanks [Darin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov)):

```
@ModelType ShoppingCartItem
@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Title )
@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Count )
<br />
```

In my controller, I’m inserting some random data, and the view  renders my shoppingcart nicely, with three items.

```
Public Class ShoppingCartController
  Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

  Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim model As New ShoppingCart
    model.Items.Add(New ShoppingCartItem With {.Count = 1, .Title = "Item A"})
    model.Items.Add(New ShoppingCartItem With {.Count = 17, .Title = "Item B"})
    model.Items.Add(New ShoppingCartItem With {.Count = 100, .Title = "Item C"})

    Return View(model)
  End Function

  <HttpPost()>
  Function Index(model As ShoppingCart) As ActionResult
    Return View(model) ' model is empty!
  End Function
End Class
```

However, when I submit the page, no values are picked up, not even the CouponCode field. The model object is empty. What gives?

Ultimately, my goal is to add/remove items clientside via javascript and then have the modelbinder pick up the changes automatically when the page is submitted.

Update: I was just missing the `Property` keyword from my model properties declarations. It's too late, and I got to get some sleep. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make the default modelbinding handle Lists?

The default model binder [already handles lists and dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) perfectly fine.

Just use editor templates. For example:

View model:

```
public class ShoppingCartItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class ShoppingCart
{
    public string CouponCode { get; set; }
    public List<ShoppingCartItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new ShoppingCart
        {
            Items = new[]
            {
                new ShoppingCartItem { Count = 1, Title = "Item A" },
                new ShoppingCartItem { Count = 17, Title = "Item B" },
                new ShoppingCartItem { Count = 100, Title = "Item C" },
            }.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ShoppingCart model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model ShoppingCart
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <fieldset>           
            <legend>ShoppingCart</legend>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CouponCode)
            <hr/>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Items)
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

and finally the editor template (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/ShoppingCartItem.cshtml`) which will be rendered for each item of the `Items` collection:

```
@model ShoppingCartItem
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Title)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Count)
```

Comment: Yup, that's the blogpost I linked to. But it's not working for me, and I can't figure out why. In Scotts example, the view model itself is a collection, whereas in my scenario the list is one of the properties on the model.

Comment: @Jakob Gade, you should use editor templates instead of writing some ugly loops in your views and manually trying to generate your input field names. I've updated my answer to illustrate you with an example. See how much easier this is? No need to write any loops and ugly views and no need to worry about field names. Everything works nicely by convention. Sorry my VB.NET is very rusty but it should be trivial for you to translate.

Comment: No joy, still the same problem. No values in the model after the POST. I've updated my sample to use an EditorTemplate - thanks, I didn't know you could use templates for collections like that. Awesome. :)

Comment: @Jakob Gade, that's very weird. My example worked perfectly fine. Let me send it to you.

Comment: Argh, crap: I got it. My property declarations were wrong. It's Public PROPERTY CouponCode As String. Everything is working now, and I really learned a few brilliant tricks from your advice. Thank you very, very much.

Comment: @Jakob Gade, ahh that's cool. I am glad you've sorted this out. Due to my rusty VB.NET skills I wouldn't have noticed that you was using fields instead of properties :-) Especially when it worked in my C# version. I was trying your code in VB.NET but now that you found out the reason it's fine.